# Don't allow embedded images from non-HTTPS sources in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, ssl

Quite often, I see a mixed content warning when looking at an SE chat room:

[image: Mixed content warning]

This is typically caused by images linked in chat hosted on an HTTP source, not an HTTPS one like the SE Imgur account. Sometimes it is also caused by oneboxing of external content (this particular example is from a onebox of the official SE blog; the blog is HTTPS, but the generated onebox isn't).

It shouldn't be possible for a user to submit content to chat that triggers inclusion of insecure content, creates this warning, and potentially compromises the security HTTPS provides.

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug that causes a mixed content warning when oneboxing posts from https://stackoverflow.blog/. How can I reproduce this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. https connections to the blog onebox, http connections do not. Is there a specific link that reproduces it?

Comment: @RougetheBat the source is in a private chat room, so I can't link it here. I created the same entry in the sandbox now: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43055441#43055441

Comment: @MadScientist I mean the URL. Which blog post is it?

Comment: And it's reproduced. It seems to be a problem with that specific image (though there could be more somewhere)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpfkw.gif gif can repro, in animated gif.

Comment: @PrincessLuna just onebox any image which isn't hosted on a site with https.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu manpages oneboxing has broken, insecure icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344399/ubuntu-manpages-oneboxing-has-broken-insecure-icon). Oneboxing *any* URL from that site will trigger a mixed content warning.