# Ubuntu manpages oneboxing has broken, insecure icon

Tags: bug, chat, ssl, onebox

Oneboxing from the Ubuntu `man` pages site appears to be using a broken, insecure icon:

> [image: Broken icon]

The broken link is http://manpages.ubuntu.com/favicon.ico.

Not only is it attempting to load the icon insecurely, triggering a mixed content warning, but the link is also 404 as of today.

The correct link should be https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/cb22ba5d-favicon-16x16.png.

This type of oneboxing is supported on all sites, not just Ask Ubuntu, so this question is not only applicable to that site.

Also, this is not a duplicate of [Icons of Meta.SE and Stack Apps have gone missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283428/icons-of-meta-se-and-stack-apps-have-gone-missing), as that is about the *network profile*, the icons are entirely internal, and the URLs remained the same but weren't working for some reason; this report is about *chat*, the icon is external (unrelated to SE), and the URL needs to be changed in order to work.

Can this please be fixed?